# Public Blog in O365, how can visitors leave response?

Tags: office-365, blog

Let's say you have a Blog site hosted in Office 365 and you write a blogpost. Users in SharePoint can comment and leave a likes, Use Hashtags and mentions. If we make the blog public so everyone can see:

Is there a OOB(Out of the Box) way to give visitors on the blog the possibility to give feedback without having a Office 365 account?

I assume I can create the functionality in an App-part that we can replace the normal "comment field" with, containing some required fields like Name, e-mail and comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to a blog on the "public" SharePoint site hosted by Office 365, it uses a Facebook plugin for comments on blog posts, not the traditional SharePoint comment list.

[image: Office 365 Blog Post]

If you are referring to a different SharePoint site hosted on Office 365, if anonymous access is configured, you can grant anonymous access for users to add items to the Comments list.